# How to set keyboard as inputview in UItextfiled

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I have one UItextfiled and in viewdidload i set his input view property as nil like this.

```
textField.inputView = nil
```

In in my view i have one button when i click on the button i have to set the textfield's inputview property as keyboard how can i do this.please help me.

Comment: why do u set inputView to nil? or functionality do u want from text filed? can you clear ?

Comment: Just to be sure : the inputView property is used to attach a view on top of the keyboard. Like a done button for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but probably you want your textField to became active, with a keyboard. That is done with

> [textField becameFirstResponder];

and other way around is

> [textField resignFirstResponder];